# Pass object property value to another property within that object in Typescript Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, automation

I have this big object in TypeScript and I'm trying to make some aspects of it automatic, to save me time.

```
myObject = [
    {
      id: 0,
      price: 100,
      isBought: false,
      click: () => this.buyItem(100, 0)
    }
buyItem (itemCost: number, itemIndex: number) {
    if (this.money >= itemCost) {
      this.myObject[itemIndex].isBought = true;
    }
```

I've already managed to automatically increment the `id` property with this function:

```
findIndex() {
    var objLength = Object.keys(this.myObject).length;
    for(let i=0; i<objLength; i++) {
      this.myObject[i].id = i;
    }
  }
```

But what I can't do is pass property values inside the object itself. In theory this is what I'm looking for.

```
myObject = [
    {
      id: 0,
      price: 100,
      isBought: false,
      click: () => this.buyItem(THIS.PRICE, THIS.ID)
    }
```

Is this possible? And if not, are there any workarounds?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach?

```
function ItemModel (price) {
    let self = this;

    self.id = 0;
    self.price = price;
    self.isBought = false;

    self.click = () => {
        buyItem(self.price, self.id);  
    };
}

var newInstanceOfItem = new ItemModel(100); // price is 100
```